# Рекомендации по выбору отслеживаемого знака по метке - предлагается метка, по коей невозможно увеличить прогресс, после её синонимизации

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток, нытьё

После синонимизирования [android-development](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-development) к [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) по первой метке невозможно увеличить прогресс, т.к. весь он идёт на вторую метку. Но система настойчиво предлагает отслеживать прогресс по первой метке.

Сие, очевидно, баг.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.**

А т.к. меня крайне расстраивает то, что система троллит меня предлагая трудиться ради достижения недостижимых целей, то тут будет метка [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91)

Comment: Потрудитесь ещё немного. Сейчас метка [нытьё] есть на 13 вопросах. Когда будет на 100, можно будет и по ней получить знак. =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вы раскрыли мой план)))

Comment: но вам для этого нужно отвечать на вопросы по метке, а не задавать )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, блин, точно) Надо срочно заняться придумыванием вопросов и ответов к ним)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объединил метки (это включает синонимизацию и замену меток). Теперь метки [android-development](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-development) вообще нет на вопросах, она существует только как синоним [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Вероятно, поможет. Если за сутки не сбросится счетчик по меткам — пишите, попробуем что-нибудь ещё.

```
updating post history, 290 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 295 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 60 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [android] and [android-development] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
22 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
6 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

UPD: ага, вижу что в [вашем рейтинге по меткам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1?tab=tags) уже нет [android-development](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-development). Значит, починилось.

Comment: Да, теперь всё отлично. Спасибо)